# One python function canceling out other

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm fairly new to Python and indeed I will have to invest more time in learning it. As for now I'm creating a portfolio using Python, Jinja2, Flask and SASS. Generally, I'm following CS50 tutorial at the moment and am modifying their code to suit my needs.

I don't fully understand their syntax, but my familiarity with functions plus reading of a documentation helped me in creating first, cool function: it takes my local time and depending on an hour it greets you appropriately (insertion into html via jinja2).

I want now to create an unordered list by applying via jinja2 elements of an array. Here is a complete code of my .py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, request, url_for
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
time = datetime.now().time()
if time.hour > (0) and time.hour < (12):
    headline1 = "Good morning,  !"
    return render_template("index.html", headline1=headline1)
elif time.hour >= (12) and time.hour < (18):
    headline2 = "Good afternoon,  !"
    return render_template("index.html", headline2=headline2)
else:
    headline3 = "Good evening,  !"
    return render_template("index.html", headline3=headline3)

def nav():
names = ["Home", "About me", "Projects", "Hobby"]
return render_template("index.html", names=names)
```

And HTML with Jinja2:

```
<body>
{% if headline1 %}
<H2>{{ headline1 }}</H2>
{% elif headline2 %}
<H2>{{ headline2 }}</H2>
{% else %}
<H2>{{ headline3 }}</H2>
{% endif %}
<ul>
{% for name in names %}
<li>{{ name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
```

Whichever function is first, it is the only working function. Whichever I'm putting as the second, it gets discarded.

Sorry if this is a noob's question, but what I'm doing wrong? Both functions are legit, but it seems that there is a problem of one function canceling out the other one. I know I have much to learn, but your answer will help me greatly in the process. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW: there is no point in using all the different headline variables, this will do. Your `nav` function is not tied to an URL and so it will not be called.

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='template')
names = ["Home", "About me", "Projects", "Hobby"]

@app.route("/")
def index():
  time = datetime.now().time()
  if time.hour > 0 and time.hour < 12:
    headline = "Good morning,  !"
  elif time.hour >= 12 and time.hour < 18:
    headline = "Good afternoon,  !"
  else:
    headline = "Good evening,  !"
  return render_template("index.html", headline=headline, names=names)
```

And HTML with Jinja2:

```
<body>
{% if headline %}
<H2>{{ headline}}</H2>
{% endif %}
<ul>
{% for name in names %}
<li>{{ name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
```